# Help with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, posix-ere

I'd like to write a regular expression that checks that a line is:

- Delimited (by a comma, for example)
- Has **at least** n # of delimited items (say 10, for example)

The items in the delimited list need not be alphanumeric. Some will have special characters.  Also, some items may be absent, so there is no assurance that there will be something between delimiters.

I'm a newb to regexp so if your answer involves anything extra clever/advanced please explain

Thanks much

Comment: Can the delimiter occur inside the delimited items? If so, in what form (inside quotes, or escaped)? E. g. `1,"2,2",3\,3,4,5`?

Comment: Hmm, didnt think of that.  If you gave both that would be awesome

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a CSV parser then, not a regex.

Comment: Thing is, I get data in a lot of formats. The only commonality is that its delimited.  Sometimes its in common CSV format, sometimes its different.  Would a CSV parser be the way to go, or using different regexps?

Comment: You should use a parser appropriate for the format, regex-based or otherwise. See: Strategy pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[^,]*(?:,[^,]*){9,}$/
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips in the comments.  Counting as an answer since this would benefit most people